# SharePoint 2019 Project templates in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: 2019, visual-studio-2019

I have a SharePoint 2019 Development server and installed VS 2019, office developer tools option from VS 2019 Installer after I launch VS 2019 I did not found SharePoint 2019 Project templates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Reinstall Office Development tools helped:

1. Run VS2019 > Tools > Get tools and features
2. Uncheck Office/Sharepoint development and click Modify
3. Wait when installation will be completed. After that install them using the same method